# Combining jQuery Functions instead of writing new (document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

Wouldn't it be more appropriate to place all of these functions inside one

```
$(document) .ready(function()
```

as opposed to declaring new jQuery for every time I want to have a function?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.someClass').is(':visible') && $('.someOtherClass').is(':visible')){
    $('.someEvenOtherClass').css('display', 'block');
    }

    });


    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.someClass').is(':visible')){
    $('.SomeNEWERclass').css('margin-top', '1px');
    }


    </script><script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.someClass').is(':visible')){
    $('.SomeNEWERclass').css('margin-top', '1px');
    }
```

Comment: yes. try codereview.stackexchange.com next time, this isn't a question so much as a confirmation.

Comment: Of course, simple maths : `less handler = better performance`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program statements are executed to handle the same event (i.e. .someClass.isVisible), then include them in the same anonymous function (btw, the second two are identical - they both set your top margin to 1px). I doubt you'll see much of an overhead improvement as a result but it will make your code easier to read, debug and/or update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using many times $(document).ready..... Just add everything to one

```
$(function(){
        //your stuff here
});
```

Comment: I didn't write the code, I'm suspecting that you don't have to but making sure before I begin to change it :-)

Comment: Lol, but if you have to declare another funtion like myFunction(){} better do it outside